# Frontend page width pits_downloadcenter extension return error

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I try to use pits_downloadcenter extension with TYPO3 9.5.7 and get the following error when I try to see the page in frontend:

> Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException [Semantical Error] The
>   annotation "@void" in method
>   PITS\PitsDownloadcenter\Controller\DownloadController::forceDownloadAction()
>   was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for
>   this annotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a pull request to the extension which can be found here: https://github.com/hojaonline/pits_downloadcenter/pull/23/files

The change is fairly easy

```
--- a/Classes/Controller/DownloadController.php
+++ b/Classes/Controller/DownloadController.php
@@ -185,7 +185,7 @@ public function showAction()
      * force download file
      * by decrypting the file uid
      *
-     * @void 
+     * @return void 
      */
     public function forceDownloadAction()
     {
```